# Is it possible to create a non-editable text box like this in streamlit ? St.write would only write but i need it in a text box

Tags: python, matplotlib, streamlit

Is it possible to create a non-editable text box like this in streamlit:

[image: Picture of a non-editable text box that includes a bullet list]

St.write would only write but I need it in a text box.

Comment: Check out [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a markdown and put it in expander.

### Code

```
import streamlit as st

percentage_value = 9

with st.expander('', expanded=True):
    st.markdown(f'''
    ##### Percentage of members with goals
    <ul style="padding-left:20px">
      <li>The percentage of members with goals in june 2020</br>
          has increased by {percentage_value} percentage.
      </li>
      <li>The percentage of members with goals is 98.</li>
    </ul>
    ''', unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

### Output

[image]